# Using variables in a teradata query

Tags: sql, variables, teradata, teradatasql

I have a request that includes a variable.
But when executing the query, it does not display the result.
I don't see the details of the error.
What's wrong with the request?

```html
DECLARE SQL_TEXT VARCHAR(3000);
DECLARE NumberInst VARCHAR(100);
SET NumberInst = '108';
SET SQL_TEXT = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM NRT_'||NumberInst||_'db_tmp.table_list';
CALL dbc.SysExecSQL(:SQL_TEXT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Legacy `dbc.sysexecsql` or `execute [immediate]` can't be used to return a result set. You should get an error message (maybe there's a condition handler suppressing it).

What you need is a result set cursor:

```
DECLARE NumberInst VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE SQL_TEXT VARCHAR(3000);

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR S1; -- result set cursor defined

SET SQL_TEXT = 'SELECT TOP 10 * FROM NRT_'||NumberInst||_'db_tmp.table_list';

PREPARE S1 FROM SQL_TEXT;
OPEN cur1; -- no result set returned when CLOSEd
```

Don't forget to define the SP using DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1